# TypeScript extending classes, not behaving logically

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typescript

I am seeing some weird behavior that I cannot explain.

I have a parent class and child class:

```
class Foo {}

class Bar extends Foo {}
```

There is some stuff happening in parent constructor and then it calls a "setup" class of the child to do some more stuff. I cannot put the child stuff in its constructor, because in parent constructor I have a condition that decides if it should happen or not.

```
class Foo {
    constructor(){
        ...
        this.startup();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public startup(){
         ...
    }
}
```

Now to the problem. In child class, I have action that takes callback, and the callback is one of the private members of that class

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    public startup(){ ... }
    public something(){
        someModule.subscribe("channel", this.onChannel);
    }
    // As a variable rather than function to support "this"
    private onChannel = (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. When I log "this" just before subscribing, the `onChannel` doesn't exist. After a lot of trial and error, I have noticed more stuff.

**Case 1**

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pjx46kh2/

If I do :

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    public startup(){ ... }
    public something(){ ... }
    private onChannel = (msg) => { ... }
}
```

It compiles to:

```
var Bar = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Bar, _super);
    function Bar() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.onChannel = function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        };
    }
...
```

And it doesn't work (described above).

**Case 2**

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9k6a2my0/1/

If I do:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    constructor(arg){
        super(arg);
    }
    public startup(){ ... }
    public something(){ ... }
    private onChannel = (msg) => { ... }
}
```

It compiles to:

```
var Bar = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Bar, _super);
    function Bar(arg) {
        _super.call(this, arg);
        this.onChannel = function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        };
    }
```

And it doesn't work.

**Case 3**

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ao02oru8/2/

If I do:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    constructor(arg){
        super.constructor(arg);
    }
    public startup(){ ... }
    public something(){ ... }
    private onChannel = (msg) => { ... }
}
```

It compiles to:

```
var Bar = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Bar, _super);
    function Bar(arg) {
        this.onChannel = function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        };
        _super.prototype.constructor.call(this, arg);
    }
```

And it works...

Obviously my code is much more complicated and actually it is dealing with quite a few events and async stuff so if you make an example in fiddle it might work just fine, but it might not.

Comment: Your last example doesn't compile using [TypeScript's playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html), it claims that the subclass constructor must contain a call to `super()` (which makes sense). So I suspect it *doesn't* work, as the transpiled `onChannel` shown is no more bound to a specific `this` than the one above it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder actually on my PC it does compile, even though with the same error, but in the end it does work. Its the only way that this works, as I mentioned in the question

Comment: *"on my PC it does compile, even though with the same error"* That's called **not compiling**. :-) If there's output at all, that's TypeScript's bad, but you can't just ignore errors. Re "working": The `onChannel` in the last transpiled block (the one you've said "works") is **identical** to the `onChannel` in the previous transpiled block (the one you've said doesn't "work"). So they'll both "work", or not "work". It might help if you defined what "works" means, but frankly, I think this is just observational error and an attempt to use a construct that isn't supported where you're using it.

Comment: I should say: An *understandable* attempt. I just don't think it works. :-) But I'm not heavy into TypeScript, could be wrong. Good luck!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes of course I want to find a way without compiler error (tahts the purpose of this question), but no - it really does work. Do not concentrate on the `onChannel` function as it is exactly the same in all examples, look at what is TypeScript doing with the `super` in each case

Comment: Could you post a complete example? I'm having trouble understanding what you mean. Where in Bar is the action that takes a callback? Where do you log *this*? Is *startup* calling *something*?

Comment: @Alex I will try to create fiddle that has the same problem.. but understand that I am using many third-party modules etc so posting code is not gonna make anything clearer. To answer your questions: Action that takes callback is not in Bar but is part of different module, hence `someModule.subscribe()`, Doesnt matter where I log `this` result is the same. Yes `startup` is calling lot of things, its basically constructor

Comment: @Alex Actually creating fiddles was surprisingly easy... I have updated question, you can see same behavior there (check console for logs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you shouldn't write code that does not pass the compiler properly. Typescript will let many errors through, but you should not take advantage of this.

What happens in your first example is that the Bar::onChannel is defined first after the call to the super constructor happens:

```
function Bar()
{
    _super.apply(this, arguments);
    this.onChannel = function (msg)
    {
        console.log(msg);
    };
}
```

Hence, your logic in the base class constructor will fail.

Methods gets defined directly on the prototype before any constructors are called (unlike fields):

```
Bar.prototype.startup = function () {
    this.something();
};
```

... so this is why you can access your methods, but not your field onChannel.

This applies on both your first and second example.

In your third example, when you write code in the derived constructor without calling super() first, you are causing the compiled code to define the onChannel first, since this is a implied assignment that should happen before your own custom logic. But I think that what this actually compiles to is to considered undefined, since it not valid typescript anyway.

What you could do if you want this kind of logical structure/flow:

```
abstract class Foo 
{
    abstract startup():void;

    constructor()
    {
        this.startup();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public startup()
    {
        this.something();
    }

    public something()
    {
        // Bind this like this instead
        someModule.subscribe("channel", (msg:any) => this.onChannel(msg));
    }

    public onChannel(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
}

class SomeModule {
    public subscribe(channel, callback){
    console.log("channel", channel);
    console.log("callback", callback);
  }
}

var someModule = new SomeModule();
var bar = new Bar();
```